# What happens to entrypoint of Docker parent image when child defines another one?

Tags: inheritance, docker, entry-point

Let's say I've got the Docker image *parent* built by this Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
ENTRYPOINT ["parent-entry"]
```

Now I inherit from this *parent* image in my child image built with this code:

```
FROM parent
ENTRYPOINT ["child-entry"]
```

As far as I have tested it the entrypoint of the child image overwrites the one in the parent image.

But since I am new to Docker I am not sure about this. My research also hasn't yet resulted in a satisfying answer. So is the assumption above correct?

Comment: The docs for [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) state: *Only the last ENTRYPOINT instruction in the Dockerfile will have an effect.*

Comment: But in this example there are TWO Dockerfiles, each with its own single ENTRYPOINT. The child Dockerfile inherits from a parent image. So the child must know the parent Dockerfile's ENTRYPOINT and either not override it, or else repeat it and add to it, correct?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The last entrypoint is used, only the last one.

You can check, put several lines with different `ENTRYPOINT` in your `Dockerfile`, and check what happens.

Comment: How can you add scripts to run after the parent ENTRYPOINT has executed?

Comment: @Stephane you don't. That's typically when you start to need an init system in your container, such as s6-overlay, tini, dumb-init, etc.