# In a Dockerfile (with MySQL base image), how can I run liquibase commands to create your schema or seed your database?

Tags: mysql, docker, liquibase

I'm having difficulty using liquibase at build time to create my schema and seed the database in an image that extends the mysql 5.7 base image. Specifically, I'm receiving a timeout because I can't connect to my database within the same singular image.

The last line in the Dockerfile below will not execute. I get the error:

```
Starting Liquibase at Thu, 16 May 2019 22:09:50 UTC (version 3.6.3 built at 2019-01-29 11:34:48)
Unexpected error running Liquibase: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

...

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65)
        ... 12 common frames omitted
```

```
FROM mysql:5.7

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE dbname

# Install wget, jdk, liquibase, mysql connector/j
...

RUN liquibase --changeLogFile=/path/to/script/schema.mysql.sql \
        --username=root \
        --password=password \
        --url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname" \
        --driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver \
        --classpath=/path/to/liquibase/liquibase.jar:/path/to/mysql-connector/mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar \
        --contexts="Initialization" \
        update
```

I'd expect for the sql script to execute to create my database schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that mysql isn't actually running yet at build time. I added this line as the last line of the dockerfile and commented out the bit that wasn't working.

```
Step 14/14 : RUN /etc/init.d/mysql status
 ---> Running in 7701598d1eff
MySQL Community Server 5.7.25 is not running.
```

Docker won't execute the entrypoint of the base image (which actually initializes the database) until the very end of the build (unless I define my own entrypoint). Source: [What happens to entrypoint of Docker parent image when child defines another one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40592662/what-happens-to-entrypoint-of-docker-parent-image-when-child-defines-another-one)

So one option would be to define my own entrypoint and copy the stuff from the base image. Probably not best practice...

Alternatively, I can use an intermediate container to seed the database after this one comes up with docker compose.